# how to Override Model admin change_form.html with custom template using admin urls

Tags: django, python-2.7

http://localhost:8000/admin/app/model/13/change/ . I want to override this change_form with another template. I need 13 from url  to use in function and reder a template

Comment: You do understand that we can't visit your localhost, right?

Comment: I gave it for reference(admin url)